# MySQL Join Query Construction

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: jobs & activities.
A job consists of zero or more activities.

```
JOBS (id,client_name,job_cost):

1, 'Kelly, Peter', '139.00'


ACTIVITIES (id,job_id,activity_name,activity_cost):

1, 1, 'Activity A', '40.00'

2, 1, 'Activity B', '59.00'

3, 1, 'Activity C', '40.00'
```

How do I write a query to retrieve the following fields:

```
DESIRED OUTPUT FIELDS:

job_id, client_name, job_cost, total_cost_of_activities, number_of_activities
```

Any help appreciated as MySQL is not one of my strong points!

Comment: +1 for wanting to do that in one query instead of multiple queries and server side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  JOBS.*,
  SUM(ACTIVITIES.activity_cost) AS total_cost_of_activities,
  COUNT(ACTIVITIES.id) AS number_of_activities
FROM
  JOBS
  INNER JOIN ACTIVITIES on ACTIVITIES.job_id=JOBS.id
GROUP BY JOBS.id
```

Comment: I think you'll want a `GROUP BY` too

Comment: @yshavit Thanks, `ERR 0xDEADBEEF: incomplete copy-paste job`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT j.id, j.client_name, j.job_cost, 
COUNT(a.id) AS number_of_activities, SUM(activity_cost) as total_cost_of_activities
FROM Jobs AS j
INNER JOIN Activities AS a ON j.id = a.job_id
GROUP BY j.id, j.client_name, j.job_cost
```

Please Note: the numeric types shouldn't be stored as `VARCHAR`s (you wrote them out in quotes).  For speed and space saving you should be using a numeric data type such as DECIMAL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT jobs.id, jobs.client_name, jobs.job_cost, 
COUNT(Activities.*) AS number_of_activities, SUM(activity_cost) as total_cost_of_activities
FROM Jobs INNER JOIN Activities
ON Activities.job_id = jobs.id
GROUP BY jobs.id, jobs.client_name, jobs.job_cost
```

EDIT: I haven't worked on MySQL. I assume that basic SQL Syntax remains same with MySQL.